# Laravel get base url on the services config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm using laravel's socialite package and would like to know how could I get the base url on the `config/services.php`?

This is for the services configuration wherein I want the redirect key to be dynamic by getting the base url of the site so I would not change this everytime I move on to a different domain or when deploying.

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '123456789',
    'client_secret' => '123456789',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost/callback',
],
```

`URL::to('/')` won't work here and I do not want to add a config on the `.env` file as it should be dynamic instead of changing values everytime on the `.env` file.

Answer (score 3):

For my projct it set by .env files:

```
'redirect' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost') . '/callback'
```

Also, you can use global variable SERVER

```
'redirect' => sprintf("%s://%s/callback",
      isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 
      'https' : 'http', 
      $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
);
```

Comment: Yeah, this could be a work around. I was thinking too much of the "laravel way" that I forgot about the native PHP .. LOL.. Would it be better if I were to use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead?

Comment: When running my application via `php artisan serve`, I am getting this PHP notice : `Undefined index: SERVER_NAME`. Take note that this only exists upon executing the artisan serve command

Comment: @basagabi: replace `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to `isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : 'localhost'`